# My websocket has two connections, one with ?sid params keeps failing, retry won't work either, but sometimes it works

Tags: javascript, websocket, phpwebsocket, laravel-websockets

My App uses `socket.io` package + `laravel-echo` package, and when it connects, it makes two requests like this screenshot.

[image]

One request without `sid` parameter is fine, and my app can work normally.

[image]

However, the one with `sid` parameter request keeps failing, I don't know why.

[image]

And that request will retry, and still failing like this.

[image]

Sometimes the request with `sid` param will work, and no matter its success or failure, my app will work normally.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Any chance you are using socket.io? Plain Websockets do not use/need this kind of parameters. Perhaps "laravel-echo" has the same functionality and this is some kind of meta information.

Comment: Yes, I'm using socket.io

Comment: socket.io is not the same as plain WebSockets. It use only WebSockets as transport and implement its own protocol on top of WebSockets: Its very well documented! https://socket.io/docs/v4#What-Socket-IO-is-not

Comment: Thank you. I thought they were kind the same.